# Merging dictionary into list issues - python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

**The problem**

I want to merge a dictionary onto the end of a list that I am generating using a For loop. It seems to work but the problem, is that the curly braces stay around the dictionary instead of merging with the list. Its kinda hard to explain so here are two examples:

This is what I want (sorry, you have to scroll to the right to see the `path` key value):

```
[{'comment': u'Fighter', 'album': u'Dead or Alive2', 'audio_offset': None, 
'title': u'You Are Under My Control ~Beautiful Version00~', 'track': None, 
'disc_total': None, 'artist': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'track_total': None, 'channels': 2, 'genre': None, 'albumartist': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'filesize': 669796508L, 
'composer': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'year': u'1999', 'duration': 403.26953333333336, 'samplerate': 48000, 'bitrate': 294651.393, 'disc': None, 
'path': '\\\\Vgmstation\\\\e\\\\Dreamcast\\\\Dead or Alive 2\\You Are Under My Control ~Beautiful Version00~.mp4'}]
```

This is what is happening:

```
[{'comment': u'Fighter', 'album': u'Dead or Alive2', 'audio_offset': None, 'title': u'You Are Under My Control ~Beautiful Version00~', 'track': None, 'disc_total': None, 'artist': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'track_total': None, 'channels': 2, 'genre': None, 'albumartist': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'filesize': 669796508L, 'composer': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'year': u'1999',
 'duration': 403.26953333333336, 'samplerate': 48000, 'bitrate': 294651.393, 'disc': None}, 
{'path': '\\\\Vgmstation\\\\e\\\\Dreamcast\\\\Dead or Alive 2\\You Are Under My Control ~Beautiful Version00~.mp4'}]
```

Notice how the braces are around the `path` key when I want that as the last key value after `disc`

Here is my relevant code:

```
import os
import subprocess
from tinytag import TinyTag
import json

tag = ''
tag_dicts = []
extf = ['$RECYCLE.BIN']
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'\\Vgmstation\\e\\Dreamcast\\Dead or Alive 2', followlinks=True):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in extf]
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(".mp4"):
            musiclist=str(os.path.join(root, name))
            tag = TinyTag.get(musiclist)
            musicpath_dict = {'path': os.path.join(root,name)}
            musiccopy = musicpath_dict.copy()
            tag_dicts.append(tag.as_dict())
            tag_dicts.append(musiccopy)


print(tag_dicts)
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
We expect a minimal working example of the problem, including appropriate code to trace the internal operation.
Your posted code fails to run, as it depends on a private file.

Comment: you should use `dict.update` if you want it be a single dictionary

Comment: This code is far from minimal.  When your post forces a horizontal scroll, you lose readers.  Fix the formatting to fit on the page.  Better yet, shorten the example.

Comment: At first glance, the problem appears to be that you `append`ed something that you wanted to be an `update`.  Read the docs for the difference, or just work through a tutorial on dicts and their methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of appending to the `tag_dicts` which is a list, you should update your dictionary inside the list. So instead of below:

```
tag_dicts.append(tag.as_dict())
tag_dicts.append(musiccopy)
```

use the below to update the dictionary:

```
tag_dicts.append(tag.as_dict())
tag_dicts[0].update(musiccopy)
```

Comment: I tried both `tag_dicts.append((tag.as_dict()).update(musiccopy))` and `tag_dicts.append((tag.as_dict()).update(musicpath_dict))` but both return back with:
`[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]`

I am going to try to do some changes and see if I can get it to work using the update method. 
Although, I am not sure if that will work as `tag_dicts` doesn't have a `path` in it. Only the `musiccopy` does.

Thanks for the lead!!

Comment: @JatonJameerJustice - I've updated my answer, have a look on it