# Trying to insert in sqlite but getting key error - python

Tags: python, list, sqlite, dictionary

**The Problem**

I am trying to insert a list into sqlite but on the **third iteration** or loop read it gives the error: `KeyError: 'path'` which is weird because the 2 results before that are perfect.

Here is what the data looks like if I `print(tag_dicts[0])` without inserting that data into sqlite:

```
{'comment': u'Fighter', 'album': u'Dead or Alive2', 'audio_offset': None, 'title': u'27 Unknown', 'track': None, 'disc_total': None, 'artist': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'track_total': None, 'channels': 2, 'genre': None, 'albumartist': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'filesize': 550450310L, 'composer': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'year': u'1999', 'duration': 332.06506666666667, 'path': '\\\\Vgmstation\\\\e\\\\Dreamcast\\\\Dead or Alive 2\\27 Unknown.mp4', 'samplerate': 48000, 'bitrate': 294651.393, 'disc': None}
{'comment': u'Fighter', 'album': u'Dead or Alive2', 'audio_offset': None, 'title': u'27 Unknown', 'track': None, 'disc_total': None, 'artist': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'track_total': None, 'channels': 2, 'genre': None, 'albumartist': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'filesize': 550450310L, 'composer': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'year': u'1999', 'duration': 332.06506666666667, 'path': '\\\\Vgmstation\\\\e\\\\Dreamcast\\\\Dead or Alive 2\\28 Unknown.mp4', 'samplerate': 48000, 'bitrate': 294651.393, 'disc': None}
{'comment': u'Fighter', 'album': u'Dead or Alive2', 'audio_offset': None, 'title': u'27 Unknown', 'track': None, 'disc_total': None, 'artist': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'track_total': None, 'channels': 2, 'genre': None, 'albumartist': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'filesize': 550450310L, 'composer': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'year': u'1999', 'duration': 332.06506666666667, 'path': '\\\\Vgmstation\\\\e\\\\Dreamcast\\\\Dead or Alive 2\\Blazed Up Melpomene.mp4', 'samplerate': 48000, 'bitrate': 294651.393, 'disc': None}
{'comment': u'Fighter', 'album': u'Dead or Alive2', 'audio_offset': None, 'title': u'27 Unknown', 'track': None, 'disc_total': None, 'artist': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'track_total': None, 'channels': 2, 'genre': None, 'albumartist': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'filesize': 550450310L, 'composer': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'year': u'1999', 'duration': 332.06506666666667, 'path': '\\\\Vgmstation\\\\e\\\\Dreamcast\\\\Dead or Alive 2\\Bomb Factory - Exciter.mp4', 'samplerate': 48000, 'bitrate': 294651.393, 'disc': None}
# there is more but I am only giving 4 results because the 3rd result is where I get the error
```

Here the code of my attempt of me inserting the data into sqlite:

```
def insert_track(con, table_name, track_data):
  sql = "INSERT INTO tracks VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
  cur = con.cursor()

  cur.execute(sql, track_data)

  conn.commit()

conn = sqlite3.connect('musicdatabase.db')
count = 0
tag = ''
tag_dicts = []
musicpath_dict = {}
extf = ['$RECYCLE.BIN']
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'\\Vgmstation\\e\\Dreamcast\\Dead or Alive 2\\', followlinks=True):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in extf]
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(".mp4"):
            musiclist=str(os.path.join(root, name))
            tag = TinyTag.get(musiclist)
            musicpath_dict = {'path': os.path.join(root,name)}
            musiccopy = musicpath_dict.copy()
            tag_dicts.append(tag.as_dict())
            tag_dicts[0].update(musicpath_dict)
            print(tag_dicts[0])

            for track in tag_dicts:
                insert_track(conn, 'tracks', (track['title'], track['album'], track['comment'], track['genre'], track['artist'], track['composer'], track['year'], track['duration'], track['path']))

conn.close()
```

But on the third, loop or iteration (the data that has the `\\\\Vgmstation\\\\e\\\\Dreamcast\\\\Dead or Alive 2\\Blazed Up Melpomene.mp4` as it's path) it will give an error:

```
{'comment': u'Fighter', 'album': u'Dead or Alive2', 'audio_offset': None, 'title': u'27 Unknown', 'track': None, 'disc_total': None, 'artist': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'track_total': None, 'channels': 2, 'genre': None, 'albumartist': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'filesize': 550450310L, 'composer': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'year': u'1999', 'duration': 332.06506666666667, 'path': '\\\\Vgmstation\\\\e\\\\Dreamcast\\\\Dead or Alive 2\\\\27 Unknown.mp4', 'samplerate': 48000, 'bitrate': 294651.393, 'disc': None}
{'comment': u'Fighter', 'album': u'Dead or Alive2', 'audio_offset': None, 'title': u'27 Unknown', 'track': None, 'disc_total': None, 'artist': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'track_total': None, 'channels': 2, 'genre': None, 'albumartist': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'filesize': 550450310L, 'composer': u'Makoto Hosoi', 'year': u'1999', 'duration': 332.06506666666667, 'path': '\\\\Vgmstation\\\\e\\\\Dreamcast\\\\Dead or Alive 2\\\\28 Unknown.mp4', 'samplerate': 48000, 'bitrate': 294651.393, 'disc': None}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\VGMSTATION\testing scripts\search and add to sqlite.py", line 97, in <module>
    insert_track(conn, 'tracks', (track['title'], track['album'], track['comment'], track['genre'], track['artist'], track['composer'], track['year'], track['duration'], track['path']))
KeyError: 'path'
>>>
```

I may make another test script and write that third result manually into sqlite (instead of using os.walk to get the path) to see if I get the same error.

I have no clue why that third result fails when the first two are fine. Any ideas are appreciated.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: You append each tag dict to the _end_ of the list, but then update the _first_ element in the list with `musicpath_dict` - is that intentional (or relevant)?

Comment: It was from an answer I got in my last question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66838734/merging-dictionary-into-list-issues-python

I was basically trying to merge the list results I get from my metadata mp4s (using tinytag) with the file path itself added to the list.

maybe i have the line's of code in the wrong order?  I will test right now

Comment: @snakecharmerb I have been doing some more testing and yeah, what you brought up is the problem. I need to have `musicpath_dict ` iterate everysingle time but its only appending the first item in the list. I am not sure how to fix this but I will find out.

Comment: `tag_dicts[-1].update(musicpath_dict)` _might_ solve it - index `-1` is always the _last_ item in a sequence.

Comment: @snakecharmerb OMG how did you know this? I kept trying [1] (only as a test) to see if it would give me the element after [0] and it kept failing. [-1] is perfect as it appended everything to the list perfectly and was able to be inserted into my sqlite base no problem! Your a life saver!!!! 

(I also fixed the indent on the for loop for the INSERT command so it doesn't loop the generating list. lol)

I wish I can mark your comment as the answer!